# Magento 2 to Lightspeed Retail

Tags: magento2, integration

We are launching a Magento 2 Website which is taking its inventory from Lightspeed Retail POS in real-time. Many M2 connectors we found (which are new versions of the ones we used on other Magento 1 sites before) seem to be removed from the market or simply do not work.

Anyone has linked the 2 platforms yet? Any tips? Or should we just convert our site to M1 for a few months?

Answer (score 0):

Accumula integrates point of sale(including Lightspeed Retail) with Magento 2. We use the Magento 2 API exclusively for stability. The Magento 2 API wasn't viable until v2.1.3 and there have been some showstopping issues in some Magento versions so we recommend caution before upgrading.

Extension selection is critical to success with Magento 2. We found that a number of Magento 2 Extensions do not follow best practice and will break the Magento 2 API. A fresh install will have no issues. We recommend testing integration while gradually adding planned extensions to ensure success.

Answer (score 0):

since Magento-Connect closed down and merged to Magento-Marketplace a lot of extensions has been wiped-out since they don't pass the extensive MEQP1/MEQP2 standards.

If you're looking for a self-hosted solution this will [integrate Lightspeed Retail POS to Magento 2](https://marketplace.magento.com/maurisource-lightspeed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Omnichannel Commerce announced free Lightspeed Retail integration with Magento 1, Magento 2 and Lightspeed POS users can now list and sell their products on multiple online sales channels simultaneously from their Lightspeed POS system. The company introduced a most cost-effective and seamless integration between the two diversified platforms having altogether different architecture.

Get detailed information here: https://www.omnichannelcommerce.biz/lightspeed-ecommerce-integration/